# How to use "interface" in the objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, interface

I need to create a class that will have the same methods as other class. In Java or ActionScript there would be an interface that my class will implement but how I can achieve this in objective-c?

I want to create custom UIProgressView without extending this class but have the same public methods (interface).

Comment: OK, so @protocol is the interface in objective-c so how to use it to implement the UIProgressView without extending it?

Comment: I think you should follow Apple Guide as @trojanfoe answered

Comment: There is no protocol defined for UIProgressView so it seems that I can't do it in proposed way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @protocol, this works similar as java interface:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
-(void)method1;
-(void)method2WithParameter:(NSString*)parameter;
@end
```

In the classes you want to implement this methods you need to conform to that protocol:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MyProtocol>
```

and you need to implement the required methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *protocol*.

See this [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

Answer (score 2):

Interface are called a [`protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) in objective-c.

```
@protocol SomeDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)someMethod;

@optional
- (void)someOptionalMethod:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

To use the interface just add it to you class like: `@interafce MyClass: NSObject<SomeDelegate>`.

If you are not sure, at runtime if the method exists, just should check it with [`respondsToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector%3a):

```
 if([self.instanceOfMyClass respondsToSelector:@selector(someOptionalMethod:)]) {
    [self.instanceOfMyClass someOptionalMethod:@"my parameter"]
 }
```